# firestore security rule check if a field is an integer

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am wondering how do I check if a field is an integer or not. I know that we are able to convert a field entry to an integer with `int(request.resource.data[field])`, but is there a way to check if `request.resource.data[field]` is an integer, return true if it is, and false it isn't?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check for type with the `is` operator.

So:

```
request.resource.data[field] is int
```

Or

```
request.resource.data.field is int
```

I highly recommend checking out Doug's video on [Data types and global objects in Firebase security rules](https://youtu.be/qbd_4LT0Y4s), specifically the section on [checking types](https://youtu.be/qbd_4LT0Y4s?t=641).