# Firestore Security rules - checking if a string can be cast to an int

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

There is [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Integer) showing how to convert a string to an int:

```
int("2") == 2
int(2.0) == 2
```

But how can I know before doing the conversion whether it will work or throw an exception?

For instance how can I implement the following:

```
IF x can be cast to an integer THEN return int(x) < 10
ELSE IF y can be cast to an integer THEN return int(y) < 10
ELSE return false
```

Comment: Firebase doesn't expose type information a priori, but you can usually determine this after you get the value. What language are you using?

Comment: I use the Web SDK, but my question is about the rules. I won't trust any check on the client side

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `int.tryParse`, which returns null if it's not parsable?

Comment: Oh, got it. I missed the fact that it's about security rules. The rules for RTDB do have explicit type check functions. For Firestore those are in the `is` keyword. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63273066/firestore-security-rule-check-if-a-field-is-an-integer. I'm not sure how you can check whether the value can be parsed though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `cast_as_int` function defined below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function cast_as_int(x) {
      let pattern = '[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+';
      return (
        (x is float)
        || (x is int)
        || (x is string) && (x.matches(pattern))
      ) ? int(float(x)) : null;
    }

    // All gets will succeed
    match /{document=**} {
      allow get: if cast_as_int(1) == 1
        && cast_as_int('2') == 2
        && cast_as_int('3.14') == 3
        && cast_as_int(4.44) == 4
        && cast_as_int("5!") != 5;
    }
  }
}
```

The function takes in an variable and returns either an [Integer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Integer) or null.
Firestore does not allow statements to evaluate to multiple types, so the function can only return `Integer` or `null` (not `false` as requested).

The function assumes you want to convert from (Integer or Float) to Integer.  If you only want to convert from Integer to Integer, then replace `int(float(x))` with `int(x)`.

The regex for `let pattern = '[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+'` was taken [this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643073/4343502)